# How to delay a fetch script in netlify function?

Tags: javascript, lambda, netlify, netlify-function

I have tried different methods like setttimeout and for loop but the script wont fire.

```
exports.handler = async function (event, context, callback) {

  const reqbody = JSON.parse(event.body);

  try {
    var yd = new URLSearchParams();
    yd.append("Author", "thea");
    yd.append("Body", reqbody.body);

    const postmessageoptions = {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        accept: 'application/json',
        'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        authorization: 'Basic ' + process.env.BASIC_TOKEN_TWILIO
      },
      body: yd
    };

    function createCustomTimeout(seconds) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          resolve();
        }, seconds * 1000);
      });
    }

    async function testing() {
      console.log('testing function has been triggered');
      await createCustomTimeout(5);
      console.log('success');
      await fetch('https://conversations.twilio.com/v1/Conversations/' + reqbody.sid + '/Messages', postmessageoptions)
    }

    testing();
    // end post message


    return {
      headers: {
        "content-type": "application/json",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
      },
      statusCode: 200,
      body: JSON.stringify('success'),
    };

  } catch (error) {

    return {
      headers: {
        "content-type": "application/json",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
      },
      statusCode: 500,
      body: JSON.stringify(error),
    }


  }



};
```

I want to delay the fetch like 5 seconds, but it returns success without firing the fetch. I could see that console.log('success') fires on console, but not the fetch.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

The `testing` is an `async` function, but you have called it **without** `await` keyword. So the program reaches the `return` statement as soon as calling `testing()` which will terminate the `lambda` and also the `fetch` requests.

```js
exports.handler = async function (event, context, callback) {

   // your code

   await testing();

   // rest of your code
}
```